# Поиск точек в окружности, сохранение времени поиска в файл. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу справится сo сложной задачей, подскажите 
пожалуйста.

1. Имеется не пустое множество точек, каждая имеет 2 координаты: Х, Y.
   Значения ограничены, X: от -5 до 5. Y: от -5 до 5. 
   То есть нужно область от (-5х -5y) до (5х 5y) заполнить рандомными точками
   (штук 500)
   Рисунок (1)

[image: Рисунок №1]

2. Выбрать точку (можно вручную, можно рандомно)
   Рисунок (2)

[image: Рисунок №2]

3. От этой точки сделать окружность (точка будет центром) с радиусом 2 см 
   (например).
   Рисунок (3)

[image: Рисунок №3]

Искать точки в этой окружности

4. Нужны тайминги поиска каждой точки, их нужно записать в файл или csv 
   или 
   txt (как удобнее).
   Рисунок (4 и 5) Если не видно что на рисунке (4), то там х= от 1 до 50, а 
   Y= 
   тайминги (только значения)

   [image: Рисунок №4]

   [image: Рисунок №5]

   y1 = 5.062406009
   y2 = 5,077913554
   y50 = 5,491269447

   ВНИМАНИЕ!!! Эти изображения для наглядности, их ненужно делать. Только код и 
   сохранение значений в файл.
   Потом по этим показаниям будет строится график "Точечная с прямыми отрезками 
   и маркерами".

   Точка x1 найдена за 5.062406009 сек и т.д.

   Таким образом получается что вся программка стартует за 5 секунд и за сотые 
   секунды ищутся точки в окружности.
   Это все. Благодарю.

## update 24.03.2019

Вот что я написал на данный момент:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#100 значений X от -5 до 5
x=np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)
print (x)
#100 значений Y от -5 до 5
y=np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)
print (y)
plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.scatter(x[50], y[50], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Как это выглядит

[image: Точка]

Теперь мне нужно как-то прописать окружность и искать какие точки в ней 
  находятся рядом с моей выбранной синим цветом.
  Время поиска каждой точки нужно сохранить в файл, по ним будет строится 
  график.

## Update 24.03.2019 (2)

Добавил окружность  [image: Рисунок7]

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time

#100 значений X от -5 до 5
x=np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)

#100 значений Y от -5 до 5
y=np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)

#Добавление окружности
circle=plt.Circle((x[50],y[50]), 2, color='blue', clip_on=True, 
fill=False)
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.scatter(x[50], y[50], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Не могу сообразить как искать точки в окружности, при этом нужно сохранить в файл время поиска каждой точки.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? PS. Просьбы о помощи, когда автор сам вообще ничего не сделал, тут достаточно быстро закрывают. Тут не "курсы для чайников"  и не биржа фриланса.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я в Python`е новичок. Хотел попросить помощи в написании этого кода. Часы гугления пока не дали плодов, решил тут вопрос задать.

Comment: ну так начинайте как все - читайте мануалы и пишите "Hello world".

Comment: Задача элементарная. Покажите, что вы _сами уже сделали_. Или укажите где конкретно возникает сложность.

Comment: Добавил свой код. На данный момент возникла сложность с вводом окружности и поиском точек в этой окружности. Так же нужно сохранить время поиска каждой точки.